# Remove Catalina Update files from Mojave

Tags: mojave, software-update, catalina

I automatically downloaded the Catalina update on my Mojave system but did not install it yet. I want to keep Mojave and therefore I want to delete the update files to save disk space.
Where are they located and how can I remove them without damaging anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/Applications/Install macOS Catalina.app
(in my case, I am-was on Catalania Beta)