# Delete macOS Catalina Installed Files

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, catalina

I have downloaded macOS Catalina, through the software upgrade, and it doesn't install for me, and it keeps adding the downloaded software to my storage, so I downloaded the OS upgrade once it went down 8 gigs, the next time I downloaded it, it went down another 8, so I lost 32 GB of storage because of the downloaded files. I was wondering how to delete these files.

Edit: There is no Install macOS Catalina.app file in my applications folder, I have checked for hidden files in that folder, and used the terminal to `ls` that directory.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Catalina Update files from Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372165/remove-catalina-update-files-from-mojave)

Comment: Hi @ankii, this solution does not work, as said file does not exist, I have already tried this.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Comment: Also check in `/Library/Updates` . I found 10.14.6 in there, doubtful about Catalina. Also, you may want to use [easyfind](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) to search for terms like "update" or "Catalina".

Comment: @ankii It seems like I may just have to perform a clean install as it is stored in a part of the operating system that I cannot access.

Comment: I just searched for `10.14.6` in easyfind and it returned me the results to /Library/Updates. you can try that for similar terms. Just allow access to file system if/ when it asks.